# How to create a Spinner and have it show different fragments?

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, android-spinner, android-fragmentactivity

After looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html, I want to know if it is possible to have Spinner show a different fragment for each item that is selected?

So for example, if my Spinner has 2 options to choose from: 'Item 1' & 'Item 2' where 'Item 1' shows 'Fragment A' and 'Item 2' shows 'Fragment B', how would I do this?

Comment: Hi Gupta, I haven't tried anything yet as I am not at my computer that has my project on. I know I will be able to get up to the point on the link, but I'm not sure what do to beyond that to implement the two Fragments

Comment: In that case, this post is likely to be shut down.

Comment: okay, I will repost when I have written the code